# Unknown "Network Error" with axios in React

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, axios

We're creating a basic automation application in React 16.13, using axios 0.18.1 to make calls to different APIs. I'm having the usual "Network Error" exception, but I can't find any information on what might be causing it. Here's what I know:

- The server is up. I can make the call in postman, curl, and in a browser, I can see the "help" page.
- I can make the call with axios in a `jest` test this way:

```js
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: SERVER,
    headers: {
     'Authorization': "Bearer " + TOKEN
    },
    adapter: require('axios/lib/adapters/http')
})
let request = instance.get(PTV_FARMS_PATH);
return expect(request).resolves.toHaveProperty('data');
```

- Other `axios.get` calls are being made in other parts of the application, tough theses use global parameters. I'm using an instance to override them.
- The API I'm trying to contact is a dotNet API (Stand by for the exact version)

Here's how I make the call (removing logic code):

```js
const InventairePTV = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('adal.idtoken');
    const PTV_SERVER = "https://my-url.com"
    const PTV_FARMS_PATH = "/rds/farms"
    const instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: PTV_SERVER,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': "Bearer " + token 
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () =>{
            await instance.get(PTV_FARMS_PATH).then((response)=>{
                setData(response.data);
                console.log(data);
            }).catch((error)=>{
                if (error.request) {
                    // The request was made but no response was received
                    console.log(error.request);
                    console.log('Error', error);
                    console.log('Message',error.message);
                    console.log('Config',error.config);
                } else {
                    // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
                    console.log('Error', error.message);
                }
            });
        }
        fetchData();
    },[instance]);

    return ()
};
```

Wether I put `adapter: require('axios/lib/adapters/http')` in the config of the instance or not doesn`t seem to make a difference.

And I always end up with this in the console of my browser (firefox 70.0 for Fedora)

```
Error Error: "Network Error"
    createError http://localhost:8080/static/js/1.chunk.js:195013
    handleError http://localhost:8080/static/js/1.chunk.js:194564
```

The `error.config` log isn't that helpful either. A tcpdump reveals that the server and the client are indeed communicating, but I wasn`t able to see what was happening. I did capture 9 packets between them tough.

Where can I go from here? What can be the issue? Can I look for more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the ASP.NET backend. We needed to enable CORS support as such:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://example.com", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
}
```

Ensure that CORS is enabled in your backend. It appears to be enforced by the browsers (because I could make the call using Jest, but not in Firefox). [This website](https://enable-cors.org/) is showing different ways to enable cors support for different backends. It appears to have multiple security implications, so I might do more research on that, but that's a great start for anyone who might have this issue.